# Issue staring Spring cloud server with rabbitmq cloud bus

Tags: spring-cloud

I am configuring spring config server with control bus(rabbitmq) but when i add its dependency the application failed to start with error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START


Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:517)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.<init>(org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer)'

The method's class, org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/D:/maven/Repo/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-amqp/5.5.2/spring-integration-amqp-5.5.2.jar!/org/springframework/integration/amqp/inbound/AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter: file:/D:/maven/Repo/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-amqp/5.5.2/spring-integration-amqp-5.5.2.jar
    org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport: file:/D:/maven/Repo/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/5.5.2/spring-integration-core-5.5.2.jar
    org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint: file:/D:/maven/Repo/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/5.5.2/spring-integration-core-5.5.2.jar
    org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport: file:/D:/maven/Repo/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/5.5.2/spring-integration-core-5.5.2.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter
```

Using spring cloud version <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>  and spring boot version 2.5.3  and my pom.xml contains following dependencies (unrelated ones are removed)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>

    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue; fixed in spring-integration-amqp 5.5.3 (Boot 2.5.4).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3606